# What is the purpose of concatenating a string and an integer?

Tags: java, string

This method returns `true` if the number passed in contains a `1`.

```
public boolean hasOne(int n) {
  return (n + "").contains("1");
}
```

What is the purpose of the  `+ ""` part? How does that make `n` a `string`? (`.contains` only works with `Strings` as far as I understand).

Comment: your second question answers the first question.

Answer (score 5):

An `int` is a primitive. Adding a primitive to a string will perform an implicit conversion of that primitive to a `String` and add the two strings together. In this case, the `int` is converted and `""` ( empty `String` ) is added,

That can be rewritten as:

```
return Integer.toString(n).contains("1");
```

or

```
return String.valueOf(n).contains("1");
```

or

```
return String.format("%d", n).contains("1");
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, the `+` operator in Java implies the use of a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object when one of the operands is a string. The Java compiler (*not* the JVM) translates this [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to bytecode instructions that invoke methods of the `StringBuilder` object to perform the concatenation.

The exact equivalent of the piece of code in the question is:

```
 public boolean hasOne(int n) {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     sb.append(n); // Which does Integer.getChars(i, spaceNeeded, value);
     sb.append("");

     return sb.toString().contains("1");
 }
```

As mentioned in other answers to this question, the `n + ""` construct is by no means an efficient way to convert a primitive integer value to a string - using [`Integer#toString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) is definitely the recommended way to do this.

**EDIT:**

While for the official Oracle JVM `"" + n` is definitely slower, as it always has been, I have encountered [some confusing results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23756966/507519) while benchmarking on my OpenJDK JVM. While I still stand by my statement that `"" + n` is sort of an anti-pattern for both performance and clarity reasons, the performance discrepancy I see on OpenJDK is quite interesting.

Comment: @user2864740: `"" + n`, however, will create at least two additional objects in the background, rather than just generate the string directly. Just because it's shorter to type doen't make it correct...

Comment: @user2864740: "a particular Java compiler"? Even the Oracle Java 8 compiler works like that when the integer operand is a variable. I would argue that, regardless if we like it or not, that would be the definitive compiler for Java ATM...

Comment: @thkala - actually it will create 3 temporary objects, which is even worse!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: actually, if you look at the implementation it may not be that bad. `Integer.toString()` creates a single temporary character array. `"" + n` creates a `StringBuilder`, which contains a temporary character array. The difference lies in the `StringBuilder` object itself and the fact that the character array is generally not created with the correct size and that it may not be allocated on the stack...

Comment: That said, I am seeing some weird results with JMH - probably due to the short runtime that does not allow for the extra garbage to become an issue...

Answer (score -1):

The "contains" method (see javadoc at [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) accepts a "CharSequent" as a parameter. The "n + """ creates a "String" object, which is a subclass of "CharSequence".