# Strings in java 8 less memory

Tags: string, memory, java-8, stringbuilder, memory-efficient

I got below code and I was asked which option gets the following pattern:

XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-2324

...

Code Below:

```
public class CCMark {

    public static String maskCC(String creditCard){

        String x = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-";
        //line 1
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(maskCC("1234-5678-1234-2324"));
        System.out.println(maskCC("4567-5678-1234-5643"));
        System.out.println(maskCC("1234-5678-1234-4654"));
        System.out.println(maskCC("4567-5678-1234-5435"));
    }

}
```

Below possible options that can be inserted on "line 1":

```
    A) 
    return x + creditCard.substring(15, 19);

    B) 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(x);
    sb.append(creditCard, 15, 19);
    return sb.toString();
```

I think that the best option here, as A and B provide us with the same output, is B, because it is using StringBuilder which means that its approach is mutable, so it will use less memory than option A.

Am I wrong? Could it be that option A for this particular situation is the best option?

Comment: in this case, a compiler does all work instead of you

Comment: So, if the compiler does all the work for me. The option A is the best approach as less lines of code is required. Right?

Comment: Except that the Java compiler does not do a lot of optimization... this isn't C++. Chances are that A will cause substantially more GC.

Answer (score 5):

Options a and b are identical, because the Java compiler will convert option a **into** option b. You could move the declaration of `x` outside the method (and make it `final`). Something like,

```
static final String x = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-";
public static String maskCC(final String creditCard) {
    return x + creditCard.substring(15, 19);
}
```

Using `javap` to check the first against, the second. Java code like,

```
String x = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-";
String creditCard = "1234-5678-1234-23324";
String x2 = x + creditCard.substring(15, 19);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(x);
sb.append(creditCard, 15, 19);
String x3 = sb.toString();
```

generates byte-code that looks like (**note** lines *6-31* **and** *32-58*)

```
 0: ldc           #16                 // String XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-
 2: astore_1
 3: ldc           #18                 // String 1234-5678-1234-23324
 5: astore_2
 6: new           #20                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
 9: dup
10: aload_1
11: invokestatic  #22                 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
14: invokespecial #28                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
17: aload_2
18: bipush        15
20: bipush        19
22: invokevirtual #31                 // Method java/lang/String.substring:(II)Ljava/lang/String;
25: invokevirtual #35                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
28: invokevirtual #39                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
31: astore_3
32: new           #20                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
35: dup
36: aload_1
37: invokespecial #28                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
40: astore        4
42: aload         4
44: aload_2
45: bipush        15
47: bipush        19
49: invokevirtual #43                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;II)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
52: pop
53: aload         4
55: invokevirtual #39                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
58: astore        5
60: return
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the compiler convert A to B? Is this automatic conversion only for this particular case? Can you please provide me with a reference link?

Comment: @MarcoPierreFernándezBurgos [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8725765/2670892) covers how StringBuilder is used in a string expression.

Comment: I doubt that it will convert `creditCard.substring` into a `append(src, from, to)` but I'm convinced it will produce a code only equivalent to `append(creditCard.substring(..))` which *is* an extra copy and object allocation. Even worse with Java 7 - substring has become more expensive.

Comment: On the other had, `final` is known to not improve performance, but only helps at preventing programming errors.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Java 7 is eol. And OP isn't using append (src, from, to), but examine the bytecode with `javap -v`. Anyway, using `static` will make it a shared `x`, making it `final` means it's eligibile for constant propagation.

Comment: In Java 6 this was cheaper (O(1) substring instead of O(n)). Java 8 is the same cost as Java 7. Also, option B *is* using `append(src, from, to)`! Mind giving the result of `javap` to show that your answer is correct?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: form A will use `substring`, but whether it requires copying of character data is JVM/JRE implementation dependent. Oracle’s recent Java 7 and Java 8 implementation don’t have an offset + length substring representation, but a JIT that knows certain string manipulation operations and may elide the copying step.

Comment: Well, let's pretend we are interested primarily in Oracle and OpenJDK, and not speculate what a different JVM could do if it existed...

Answer (score 2):

The big advantage of the variant A, `return x + creditCard.substring(15, 19);` is that it is simple and clean and it works in all Java versions from `1` to `8`. In the case that its compiled form uses `StringBuffer`, a simple recompile for Java 5 or newer will make it use `StringBuilder` instead. This flexibility is lost when you work with either, `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`, manually.

The exact compiled form is not fixed. Since the semantic of the method `String.substring` is not fixed by the Java Language Specification, compilers usually won’t touch this and compile it as an ordinary method invocation. The specification *encourages* compiler vendors to use `StringBuilder` for string concatenation (the `+` operator) whenever there is a benefit and most compilers will do so, even when there is no benefit. Here, both, `x` and the result of `substring`, are `String`s so a simple `String.concat` would be simpler but most compilers always use `StringBuilder`, compiling variant A to the equivalent of
 `return new StringBuilder().append(x).append(creditCard.substring(15, 19)).toString();`.

Comparing this typical form with your variant B, we can conclude that variant B has two advantages performance-wise:

- `new StringBuilder(x)` initializes the `StringBuilder` to a capacity of `x.length()+16` which is sufficient for the entire operation, whereas the default capacity of `new StringBuilder()`, typically used for variant A, is fixed to `16` characters which misses the mark here as we have a result of `19` characters, thus a reallocation and copying of the underlying character array will occur
- `sb.append(creditCard, 15, 19);` will copy the four characters without the need to create an intermediate `String` representation of these characters. The expenses of the `substring` operation differ depending on the implementation, e.g. in Oracle’s implementation there was a significant change with version `1.7.0_06`; starting with this version a substring requires a new `char[]` array holding a copy of the affected character data as it doesn’t maintain a separate `offset` and `length` field

But note that all these differences of variant A and B only affect the formal description of the operation to perform. What will actually happen, is up to the JVM/JRE and usually the Hotspot optimizer knows a lot of string related operations and may fuse operations or elide intermediate string representations. Thus, the outcome regarding performance is rather unpredictable and may be affected by [subtle changes to the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23756966/2711488).

That’s why developers might stick to variant A which is, as said, simpler and more readable, and only care for performance once a profiler tells them that there is a performance problem that could be solved by dealing with `Stringbuilder` manually.

Comment: I think A is the best option too.